# sql update query in php

Tags: php, sql, excel, web

I am trying to do an update query in php to update my database but the query is not working. It is probably something simple.

```
$query = "UPDATE Events 
          SET charity_name = '$charity_name' ,
              charity_reg = $charity_reg ,
              Event_Name = '$event_tit', 
              Event_Status_Code = '$event_stat', 
              Start_Date = $event_dat, 
              Hours = $event_hour, 
              location = '$event_loc', 
              Other_Details = $event_content,
              event_image = $imageData, 
              image_name = '$imageName', 
              max_available_spaces = $event_spaces, 
              Event_type = '$eve_category', 
              event_cost = $event_cost, 
              event_organiser = '$event_organiser' 
          WHERE Event_ID = $the_event_id";
```

Comment: which database system are you using?

Comment: try semicolon at the end of the SQL. Do you recieve any error message?

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Do not munge query strings with literal values.

Comment: Any errors being returned by MySQL (or whatever database server you're using)?

Answer (score 1):

You are not putting quotes ('') around some values, that might be a problem unless all thoses values are boolean/ints. Make sure to put quotes around all values, like `'$imageData'` instead of `$imageData` Also watch out for sql injections when you are directly inputting the values in your query. Better to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

```
$query = "UPDATE Events 
          SET charity_name = '$charity_name' ,
              charity_reg = '$charity_reg' ,
              Event_Name = '$event_tit', 
              Event_Status_Code = '$event_stat', 
              Start_Date = '$event_dat', 
              Hours = '$event_hour', 
              location = '$event_loc', 
              Other_Details = '$event_content',
              event_image = '$imageData', 
              image_name = '$imageName', 
              max_available_spaces = '$event_spaces', 
              Event_type = '$eve_category', 
              event_cost = '$event_cost', 
              event_organiser = '$event_organiser' 
          WHERE Event_ID = $the_event_id;";
```

EDIT: as @dWinder mentioned: if `$the_event_id` is not an integer, make sure to also put quotes around that value.

Comment: @dWinder `$the_event_id` is probably an integer so you should not make it a string but keep it an integer..

Comment: @dWinder OP left a lot of information out in his question (like all the values of all the variables and how he is executing the query and what kind of error he is getting). This is my best guess

Comment: @dWinder added it to my answer